# Some mongoclient class function doesn't work

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using mongoclient of php. I met a trouble. The function of `remove()` doesn't work but `find()` method works well. If you know the reason, could you tell me. Thanks.

```
<?php
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB("mydb");
$coll = $db->selectCollection("users");
$coll->remove(array("name" => "MonogDB"));
$docs = $coll->find();
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What happens? Errors?

Comment: Get you some errors or have you no write permissions on the mongoDB?